# Deleting multiple XML elements between too elements

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I have some XML which looks like the following:

```
<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
```

Using Python, I would like to delete all items between `item1` and `item5` without having to name it explicitly, to get the following result:

```
<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
```

With `lxml`, I know how to find `item1` and `item5` so I just need to know how to build some kind of list of XML elements which are between these two.

Comment: In Python it is often much easier to read the file, remove the desired parts and then rewrite the file. It may be different with the modules you're using, idk.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. In my case, it would be difficult to access the file as it goes in a bigger use case but if I find no other solution, I'll think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to alecxe, I found the solution. His answer works perfectly for the case described but didn't work (even with his update) if we have multiple instances of item1-item5 elements (see my comment to his answer to understand better).

Anyway, I found another solution (which I believe is simpler and more Pythonic):

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring

data = """<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
"""

tree = fromstring(data)

item1_list = tree.findall("item1")

for item1 in item1_list:
    next_node = item1.getnext()
    while next_node.tag != "item5":
        tree.remove(next_node)
        next_node = item1.getnext()

print(tostring(tree))
```

---

There is also a solution coming from alecxe comment which works for me:

from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring

```
data = """<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
"""

tree = fromstring(data)
node_start = "item1"
node_end = "item5"

parent = tree.xpath("//FirstLevel")[0]
# Remove first section
for node in parent.xpath("*[(preceding-sibling::item1)[1] and (following-sibling::item5)[3]]"):
    parent.remove(node)
# Remove second section
for node in parent.xpath("*[(preceding-sibling::item1)[2] and (following-sibling::item5)[2]]"):
    parent.remove(node)
# Remove last section
for node in parent.xpath("*[(preceding-sibling::item1)[3] and (following-sibling::item5)[last()]]"):
    parent.remove(node)

print(tostring(tree))
```

I found the correct indices to put in `preceding-` and `following-sibling` by trying multiple values and still didn't really get the logic behind it but it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) and [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling), example:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring, tostring

data = """<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item2>Val2</item2>
    <item3>Val3</item3>
    <item4>Val4</item4>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
"""

tree = fromstring(data)
node_start = "item1"
node_end = "item5"

parent = tree.xpath("//FirstLevel")[0]
for node in parent.xpath("*[preceding-sibling::%s and following-sibling::%s]" % (node_start, node_end)):
    parent.remove(node)

print(tostring(tree))
```

Prints:

```
<FirstLevel>
    <item1>Val1</item1>
    <item5>Val5</item5>
</FirstLevel>
```

---

If you can have multiple occurrences of `item1` and `item5` inside a single node:

```
item_start = "item1"
item_end = "item5"

parent = tree.xpath("//FirstLevel")[0]
for node_start in parent.xpath("%s" % item_start):
    for node in node_start.xpath("following-sibling::%s" % item_end):
        parent.remove(node)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which works perfectly in the case described.
However, if we consider the case when we repeat twice our "itemN" elements (to have item1 to item5 and then item1 to item5 again), it would remove all elements between the first item1 and the last item5. How could I get item1, item5, item1 and item5 again. I hope that it's clear :)

Comment: @filaton I think I understand what you meant. Please see the update. Thanks.